# for a python flask web app deployed on heroku. how front end know dynamic backed server port?

Tags: python, heroku, flask, socket.io

The question could also be :
how javascript get heroku env variable PORT?

I have a falsk web app. 
the backend server run like below

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))

socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

my frontend client need to communicate with my server back and forth and I need to know which port backend is listenning.

In frontend index.html, i have below java script

```
socket = io.connect('0.0.0.0:5050'+ namespace);
```

My problem is, how do I know the dynamic port from backend?

I deployed my app on heroku, which i can't bind a fixed server. I have 
setted my heroku config var like

```
Config Vars
PORT: 5050
```

I thought every time my app is redeployed, this port would be grabbed and used but it isn't like that. Every time I re-deploy, server listening on a random port.

Can someone help, thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the location object in the web client to find out everything you need to know about the server.

```
var HOST = location.origin.replace(/^http/, 'ws')
var ws =  io.connect(HOST + namespace);
```

However, in the documentation below they show the client side socket being initialized without arguments. Have you tried this?

```
 var socket = io();
```

I'm guessing using the "default constructor" accomplishes the same as the above: use the location and change the protocol.

Also they say you would enable session based affinity.

This is all from the heroku sockets docs https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets Though the article refers to a node based server, the principle the same with flask.

Comment: my front end is a html page having java script blocks, I am not knowing node.js very much, just want to know if the link you gave will also work for my case ?

Comment: I tried your method. when test it locally, HOST is url:port . but when deploy to heroku and test it, HOST only have url but have no port info, and frontend cant connect to backend after deploy. do you have any clue why is it?

Comment: i got some error as follow : socket.io.min.js:2 GET my-web-site/socket.io/1/?t=1482034092269 503 (Service Unavailable)

Comment: I checked detail about above error, basically, this means the io.connect() failed. When I run locally, i don't have this issue, I still think this is caused by port missing. :(

Comment: See amended instructions from the doc.

Comment: thank you for your reply, var socket = io(); doesn't work, the problem is how to  connection to the right port, the new way no even define connection ..I might switch to use aws to deploy..

Comment: If you are serving your HTML page from the same application as the socket server, any off these methods would work.  There is something you aren't telling us.

Comment: hey... it turns out all you said is correct. And my problem is due to the version either of flask socket-io or web socket io installed in heroku is not update and some method not working properly. After I sync all versions with my local, problem solved. thanks a lot !